how to correctly install expo app for react-native
When attempting to install expo, I receive this error:

Something went wrong in downloading and extracting the project files: Could not parse JSON returned from "npm.cmd pack expo-template-blank@latest --dry-run".
expo-template-blank-50.0.39.tgz
Error: Unexpected token 'e', "expo-templ"... is not valid JSON
Error: Could not parse JSON returned from "npm.cmd pack expo-template-blank@latest --dry-run".
expo-template-blank-50.0.39.tgz
Error: Unexpected token 'e', "expo-templ"... is not valid JSON.

I tried the following:

update node
reinstall expo cli

But neither worked, what other steps can I try?

Try to update your npm version :  npm install -g npm or npm install -g npm@latest
If that doesn't work, switch to the lastest version of Node LTS.

Install the latest Node version: nvm install --lts

Switch to latest version: nvm use --lts


